# Is it possible to show this integral is increasing in $t$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

We know function $f(s)$ is increasing in $s$ for $s\in[0,\infty)$.

Is it possible to show that
$$\int_{t}^{\infty}f(s)e^{\alpha(t-s)}ds$$
is also increasing in $t$ for $t\in[0,\infty)$ when $\alpha>0$?

In some numerical instances, it is true but I'm curious if this is true in general.

Could someone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F(t)=\int_t^\infty f(s) e^{\alpha(t-s)}ds$, then by setting $s=t+x$ we have
$$
F(t)=\int_0^\infty f(t+x) e^{-\alpha x}dx
$$
Hence if $t_2\ge t_1$ then
$$
F(t_2)-F(t_1)=\int_0^\infty [f(t_2+x)-f(t_1+x)] e^{-\alpha x}dx\ge 0
$$
since the expression in the square brackets is non-negative due to monotonicity of $f$.

So the answer is yes.